# Bayesian-NN with Tensorflow probability: predictions not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, bayesian-networks, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to implement a Bayesian neural network for genomic predictions. My X is a matrix that is scaled and gets normalized so that the values are between 0 and 1. The y is a vector of values that are again normalized so that the values are between 0 and 1.

The network seems to learn as seen here:

[image]

But, when I try to make predictions these look strange and seem to behave randomly. While the true values of y are distributed between 0 and 1. The predicted values are between ~ 0.4 - 0.6 and my R2 is negative. The MSE is around 0.02, what seems not to bad, but might be caused by the fact that the range of the predictions is quite narrow.

[image]

I'm a bit running out of ideas what could be wrong. Any suggestions are appreciated :).

I've also tried to predict the training data. That is also not working and I'm getting a negative R2.

X has the dimensions (5000,500) and y (5000,)

Increasing the number of hidden layers (up to 3) and units (upt to 128) doesn't change anything.

```
# Import necessary packages:

import sys

from os.path import join
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from IPython import display

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import kerastuner as kt

from keras import backend as K
from keras import activations, initializers
from keras.layers import Layer

import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs
import tensorflow_docs.modeling
import tensorflow_docs.plots

import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import time
import tempfile
import math
import statsmodels.api as sm

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, BayesianRidge
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, scale

from pandas_plink import read_plink
from pandas_plink import read_plink1_bin
from pandas_plink import get_data_folder

tfd = tfp.distributions

# Set random seed and start timer

np.random.seed(12345)
start = time.time()

### functions

def get_optimizer():
    return tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()

def get_callbacks():
    return [
        #tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots(),
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1, patience=500, restore_best_weights=True),
        ]

def normalize_data(df):
    return (df - df.min())/(df.max() - df.min())

def compile_model(model, optimizer=None):
    if optimizer is None:
        optimizer = get_optimizer()
        
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
    
    return model

def MSE(test,pred):
    sqr_err = np.subtract(test,pred)**2
    return sqr_err.mean()

# ## load & preprocess data

# ### load genotype data

G = np.genfromtxt("genotype.txt")
G[np.isnan(G)] = 0.

G = normalize_data(G)
print(G.mean())
print(G.var())

# ### load phenotype data

traits = np.genfromtxt("phenotype.txt")

traits = normalize_data(traits)
print(traits.mean())
print(traits.var())

# ### split training and validation set

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(G, traits, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

X = np.concatenate((train_X, test_X), axis=0)
y = np.concatenate((train_y, test_y), axis=0)

# ### parameter definition

N = G.shape[0]
p = G.shape[1]

NUM_FOLDS = 5
kfold = KFold(n_splits=NUM_FOLDS, shuffle=True)
INPUT_SHAPE = X.shape[1]
OUTPUT_SHAPE = y.shape[0]
BATCH_SIZE = 32
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = math.ceil((X.shape[0]*(1-1/NUM_FOLDS)*0.8)/BATCH_SIZE)
MAX_EPOCHS = 5000

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['method','MSE','R2'])
histories = {}

# Specify the surrogate posterior over `keras.layers.Dense` `kernel` and `bias`.
def  posterior_mean_field(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    c = np.log(np.expm1(1.))
    return tf.keras.Sequential([
        tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(
            tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :n],
                       scale=1e-5 + tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:])),
            reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)),
    ])

# Specify the prior over `keras.layers.Dense` `kernel` and `bias`.
def prior_trainable(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return tf.keras.Sequential([
        tfp.layers.VariableLayer(n, dtype=dtype),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(
            tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1),
            reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)),
    ])

def neg_log_likelihood(y_true, y_pred, sigma=1.0):
    dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=y_pred, scale=sigma)
    return K.sum(-dist.log_prob(y_true))

#neg_log_likelihood = lambda y, p_y: -p_y.log_prob(y)

kl_loss_weight = 1.0 / STEPS_PER_EPOCH

histories = {}

fold_no = 1
for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,)),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(units=32,
                                    make_posterior_fn=posterior_mean_field,
                                    make_prior_fn=prior_trainable,
                                    kl_weight=kl_loss_weight,
                                    activation='sigmoid'),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(units=1,
                                    make_posterior_fn=posterior_mean_field,
                                    make_prior_fn=prior_trainable,
                                    kl_weight=kl_loss_weight,
                                    activation='sigmoid'),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1)),
    ])
    
    model.compile(loss=neg_log_likelihood, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), metrics=['mse'])
    
    history = model.fit(X[train], y[train],
                        validation_split = 0.2,
                        steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                        epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                        callbacks=get_callbacks(),
                        verbose=0)
    
    histories['BNN2_'+str(fold_no)] = history
    
    y_pred_list = []
    for i in range(500):
        y_pred = model.predict(X[test])
        y_pred_list.append(y_pred)
    
    y_preds = np.concatenate(y_pred_list, axis=1)
    y_mean = np.mean(y_preds, axis=1)
    m_err = MSE(y[test],y_mean)
    r2_acc = r2_score(y[test],y_mean)
    df = df.append({'MSE':m_err, 'R2':r2_acc, 'method':'BNN2'}, ignore_index=True)
   
    
    fold_no = fold_no + 1
    
df.to_csv("results.csv")
```

Comment: It seems like the model is underfitting. Could you try to increase the number of parameters? Or maybe more hidden layers.

Comment: I've tried to increase the number of layers and units, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Instead of sigmoid function can we try to use relu as activation. (Usually using sigmoid in the hidden layers is a bad practice, since it's hard to differentiate due to the vanishing gradient problem). Also, try to increase standard deviation as a trainable parameter, by doing so you can increase the exploration area for the posterior dist.